# Lightning supresses custom classes in VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, stylesheets, styleclass

I ran into an issue where a VisualForce page containing custom style classes (in the head tag), and which displays fine in Classic, gets the custom classes supressed in Lightning. If raw styles are used (without classes), then those work.

Did anyone experience this and if yes then how can custom classes be used within VisualForce under Lightning?

Thanks ahead for your freedback on this.

Comment: please share code of both situations

Comment: I found the offending styles. Any custom class preceded by "td" did not render within Lightning. So, for example, by changing "td .custom-class-name" to ".custom-class-name" (without "td") fixed the issue.